# Create and copy whole cell before NotebookApply

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I have created a button with a NotebookApply associated, something similar to the following

```
Button["Apply",
 Block[{in = InputNotebook[]},
  NotebookApply[in, "x + 1/\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]; 
  SelectionEvaluate[in]]]
```

This is used on expressions such as `z + y + Expand[(1 + x)^4] + 1` where I select (highlight) `Expand[(1 + x)^4]`, then press the "Apply" button to get `z + y + x + 1/Expand[(1 + x)^4] + 1`

I would like to modify the function so that I keep a copy of the original cell before the application of the button (i.e. the original `z + y + Expand[(1 + x)^4] + 1`) to keep track of the steps done (the copied cell could be above or below the original one).

Any ideas on how to implement this? I have tried to use SelectionMove but I haven't found a way with to select-and-copy the whole cell while keeping the initial selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

```
Button["Apply", 
  Block[{in = InputNotebook[], oldCell, oldBoxes},
    oldBoxes = NotebookRead[oldCell = First@SelectedCells[]];

    NotebookApply[in, "x + 1/\[SelectionPlaceholder]"];
    SelectionEvaluate[in];

    SelectionMove[oldCell, Before, Cell];
    NotebookWrite[in, oldBoxes];
    SelectionMove[oldCell, After, CellContents];
  ]]
```

For the record: `SelectionEvaluate` does not do anything here or in your example.

Comment: That's great, thanks. You are right, SelectionEvaluate is not necessary in the example provided.